# Are questions about debugging OpenGL shaders on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Technically speaking, questions for debugging would be on-topic on Stack Overflow. However, a bit of overlap between Stack Exchange sites is not unusual, and the community over here might be able to provide some insights in the broader area of computer graphics.

So, would questions about debugging OpenGL (or OpenGL ES) be on-topic?

Comment: Oh, there will be tons of overlap with SO anyway. But well, which promgramming-oriented site doesn't have those? I don't think that's something to worry much about.

Comment: `promgramming` that word describes my high school dance experiences.

Answer (score 16):

### Yes, they are

Debugging shaders can be quite different from "normal" debugging, and involves very unique challenges. Furthermore, someone not working with computer graphics will never encounter these issues. It's important to have these questions in this community where we have computer graphics experts to answer them, and where people seeking help with CG programming will likely try to find them.

(Coincidentally, [this was my only score-11 example question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74985/computer-graphics/75107#75107) during the definition phase, so I guess this topic would indeed be quite popular.)

Answer (score 2):

This site is for a 3d (or any graphics) programing, and as such the debugging part belongs here. It is also highly specialized programming and especially challenging to debug.

So yes it definitely belongs here

Comment: [Not *only* 3d programming](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/38/is-this-site-only-about-3d-topics), I hope?

Comment: @trichoplax n-dimensional computer graphics and graphics programming :D

Answer (score -2):

The [openGL tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengl) is very active on SO. Which I mean to take that there are a lot of experienced graphics programmers willing to help with debugging openGL.

A lot of them will never venture near our little SE site.

I also envision that the answers provided here will be more theory based than what SO would provide. There they would focus on the specific piece of code and its problems.

Comment: I would like us to work on attracting such experts. If they are already active in the tag on SO then they already want a place to answer such questions, so they may just need to hear about us.

Comment: I expect answers here to reflect the question, so a theory question gets an answer to "how does this work?" and a practical question gets an answer to "why is this broken?".

Comment: Are you saying we should avoid OpenGL questions here, or just that we won't be ready to give the best answers until we attract a larger group of experts?

Comment: no I'm saying that implementation issues are best served at SO while theoretical ones are better here (and they would be too broad for SO)

Comment: Ah I see. I see this as a site for the implementation issues *and* the theoretical ones. I see a grey area between them, and I also don't think programmers and researchers will always know which is which before the question is answered, so I'd like to see everything here.