# What should our on-topic page look like?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, on-topic

We now have several question asking whether specific things are on-topic but nothing in the [on-topic help page](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

What should be written there?

Comment: Topicness discussion isnt really over yet, the beta is for the discussion. We also do not yet have mods so theres nobody who can edit this page untill next week or so.

Answer (score 3):

This is what just went live:

---

> **Computer Graphics Stack Exchange** is for computer graphics researchers and programmers.
>
> Topics that are usually a good fit for this site include:
>
> - Questions about math related to computer graphics,
> - Questions about a specific graphics [programming](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67/are-questions-about-api-specific-stuff-on-topic) or [debugging](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-questions-about-debugging-opengl-shaders-on-topic) problem,
> - Questions about a specific [graphics API](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67/are-questions-about-api-specific-stuff-on-topic),
> - Questions about a specific graphics algorithm or concept.
>
> If your question generally covers (one of) these topics, then you’re in the right place to ask your question!
>
> ---
>
> However, some questions are still off-topic, although they might fit into the above criteria.
>
> - Questions asking for [off-site resources](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146/are-questions-asking-for-off-site-resources-on-topic) including books, tools and tutorials are off-topic as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Also, the other sites may remove their content, which makes the question here useless for future visitors. Instead, ask about the specific problem you have.
> - The same applies to questions asking for [software recommendations](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/are-questions-about-software-recommendation-in-scope). You may ask such questions on [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but please first read over their [Help Center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).
> - Questions about [how to use (a feature of) modeling software](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/is-asking-about-maya-or-3ds-max-blender-api-on-topic) are off-topic here, but may be suitable to [Super User](http://superuser.com). Questions specific to Blender may even be asked on [Blender Stack Exchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com). Again, please have a look into their Help Centers before asking.
> - Questions about [Computer Vision](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/is-computer-vision-in-scope) are off-topic, except where it overlaps with computer graphics. As there is a significant part of overlap between these two topics, the line is blurry. Also, a site dedicated to Image Processing and Computer Vision is [already proposed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86832/image-processing-and-computer-vision), or have a look at [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com) and their Help Center.
>
> ---
>
> Please [look around](/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](/helpcenter/self-answer).
>
> If your question is not specifically on-topic for Computer Graphics Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

---

<sub><sup>Some parts stolen from StackOverflow, German SE or Startups SE.</sup></sub>

The last part is the standard/default text every new site has and is already there. Also many other sites include it in their on-topic page.

Comment: The link to the [Computer Vision proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86832/image-processing-and-computer-vision) will stop working if they go 12 months without reaching beta, which is due to happen on 1st May 2016. We'll need to remember to check at that point whether the link needs editing.

Comment: @trichoplax Yep, that's right. I'm interested in and following that proposal anyway, so I will notice when it hopefully proceeds to commitment/beta or if it is closed.

Comment: Modeling software includes other things than just 3d modeling.