# Is computer vision in scope?

Tags: discussion

Is computer vision considered computer graphics? If not are these questions within scope here. We currently have a question about image recognition here:

- https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1549/real-time-number-plate-localization-object-detection

Then we have questions on 3d reconstruction from images. Are these in scope?

Extrapolating further: Is laser scanning and radar imaging in scope? Is radiology in scope? What about camera sensors and photography? When do you actually fall out of scope and when not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Computer vision is off topic except where it overlaps with computer graphics

Computer vision is in some sense the opposite of computer graphics - going from image to description rather than from description to image. However, despite this intuitive difference, computer vision contains many aspects of computer graphics, and computer graphics often requires techniques which overlap with computer vision. The line between the two will therefore always be blurred.

***There will be many questions for which is it is clear that they are not about computer graphics. I believe that the numberplate recognition question is one of these, and I have voted to close it as off topic.***

#### Grey areas

Although recognition questions are off topic, questions about construction of a model based on measured data such as photographs or laser scans are in some cases on topic, and are an important part of work and research in computer graphics.

It is hard to intuitively describe the difference, in order to guide people who are considering voting to close. What might help is to think of recognition as a categorisation problem rather than a construction problem.

This certainly won't provide a clear outcome for all the grey area questions, which is why we need human close voters rather than an algorithm or a strict rule.

Comment: I don't agree, maybe because i am better prepared on Computer vision topics than in Computer Graphics. Maybe we can accept CV question until the CV / Image Processing board is open. Can we?

Comment: @psicomante although the scope of sites does change over time (sometimes significantly) I personally think that we need to define our scope at the moment independently of expectations of future sites. To get an answer that isn't just my personal opinion it might be worth you asking a new question on Meta. It seems a subtly different question from this one that will probably attract different types of answer.

Comment: Where can I ask a question about CV?

Comment: @kelin You could look around Stack Exchange's [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) where new question and answer sites are born, and either find a proposal that suits what you're looking for, or start one of your own.