# Is this graphics or image processing? Is there an overlap?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

The question [What is the state-of-the-art on using computers to “clean-up” images?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1880/what-is-the-state-of-the-art-on-using-computers-to-clean-up-images) has a comment to say:

> This question is about image / signal processing, which is not within the scope of this site. However, there is a SE for signal processing here: [dsp.stackexchange.com](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

This question does indeed appear to be [on topic for Signal Processing](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63/computer-vision-questions-are-on-topic-or-off-topic). Is it also off topic here?

---

*Note that as image processing seems to be a different topic to general computer vision, I consider this a distinct meta question from [Is computer vision in scope?](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/is-computer-vision-in-scope)*

Comment: I think it should be in this forum: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86832/image-processing-and-computer-vision

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is on topic. Sure it has overlap with several other stackexhange sites. That in itself is not, and should not be considered a problem.

If that question is off topic then that means most filtering and many texture generation questions are also possibly out of topic. So in a wider scope, computer graphics is often signal processing. Example of a question that is in this category:

- [how-does-a-computer-upscale-1024x768-resolution-to-1920x1080](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1862/how-does-a-computer-upscale-1024x768-resolution-to-1920x1080), which is in essence a question about a similar thing. But it clearly is on topic in most users mind.

So no it's fine here.

Answer (score -2):

Per this discussion I went ahead and cross-posted this in the other two suggested SE forums to acquire their viewpoints and expertise on this matter. So far (it is still a little "early in the day" so to speak) I have received some pretty interesting information in 2 of the 3.

When this is all done (when good answers have been selected) I would appreciate a way to merge these **for the benefit of all three SE communities**:

- Computer Graphics: [What is the state-of-the-art on using computers to "clean-up" images?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1880)
- Signal Processing: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28168
- Video Production: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17363

Comment: Even though I've already said this on your original question, I'll add my comment here too for anyone who arrives here first:

Comment: Although this was with good intentions, note that [cross posting on several SE sites is not recommended](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: Thing is if you cross post a question then it means you have not made due diligence. Since nearly all SE sites require you to show effort this is bad, since you invalidating your own implied claim that your question is worth answering. If you can not decide where the question should live consider that the question itself is too broadly scoped.

Comment: Isn't any question about the status of the *state-of-the-art* by definition a "broadly scoped" question? In this case I asked in CG believing that was the correct forum and my question was almost immediately challenged that it was in the wrong forum. It was the challenge and the response to that challenge that expanded the paradigm. Sadly, I came to SE to contribute and learn because I have become soooo tired of all the "challenge" drama at Wikipedia. I have an advanced vocabulary of almost 100,000 words and the only one I want to use right now is this *sucks*!

Comment: Yes and thus thats why it out of scope on many forums. I didnt challenge you, your reaction speed is way too high for the functioning of this site. You should be reactin at one action per half a day for the individual consensus having time to react.

Comment: No, you did not challenge me. @trichoplax challenged the *on topic*-ness of the question. As far as the "reaction speed" issue *p l e a s e* show me anywhere in SE that is spelled out to new (or even older) users? I am not saying you are wrong, *but by-golly gee-whiz somebody shoulda told me!* :P

Comment: It isnt said, but a community of thousands of people moves slowly. One person is hardly ever indicative of entire communities. CG is slow because there are so few of us visiting any day,

Comment: @O.M.Y. Please understand what has really happened: I didn't challenge the on topic-ness of your question. I noticed that someone else had, in a comment. Since their comment does not necessarily reflect the opinion of the community, I raised this meta question so the community could express how they feel about your question. So far the only response has been that it is definitely on topic.

Comment: @trichoplax Thanks for the clarification and my apologies for misreading the intent.

Comment: @O.M.Y. No problem. We are a very new community compared to the other Stack Exchange sites, so you will see a lot of discussion about what is on topic - we're still deciding...